# Is there any way to remove the license indicator on a GitHub repository even if the license is deleted?

Tags: github, licensing

[image]

Refer to the highlighted part of the image above, I have tried adding a LICENSE file from GitHub to one of my repository.

Upon deleting the LICENSE file, the license indicator (highlighted on the image above) did not disappear.

How do I make it disappear? The repository is old and I don't want to create a new one because the commit history might be deleted.

Already tried clearing cache on browsers, re-adding and removing a LICENSE file again (assuming it's just a glitch) but to no avail.

Expecting a repository overview like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If you remove the license, your code becomes *all rigths reserved*.

(https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Is this your intention? If you intend to remove the **requirement to include the original copyright notice** you should replace the license to *MIT-0* instead. It is good practice to include any kind of license that mirrors your intention.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub uses [`licensee/licensee`](https://github.com/licensee/licensee) to detect a license.

Make sure there are no remnants of the license text in *other* files, such as the `README.md` or in the source code headers.
If the license indicator persists after the `LICENSE` file has been removed and there is no trace of the license text anywhere else in the repository, you may need to contact GitHub support. They can manually remove the cached license indicator.

The Licensee tool might run on all branches and tags, so make sure the `LICENSE` file is not present on another branch or in the repository's tags.

Sometimes it takes a while for GitHub's cache to refresh. It may disappear after some time without any further action required.